# how to put an issue to a repository whose "issue" entry is closed?

Tags: github, issue-tracking

My boss gave me an assignment through a Github repository, which only contains a readme file. The file ask me to fork the project and "***Anything unclear about the feature, fire issue on github***". I've already forked the project and "issue" entry on original repository is closed, so how can I make a new issue and make my boss to notice that?

Answer (score 0):

If you make a new issue, you can tag your boss in the issue by just typing in his/her user name in the issue form. Your boss will be tagged as a participant in the issue

So your issue would look something like this.

> Some issue goes here
>
> @your_boss_username